# Visual Webpart Data Loading in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Sorry if this is a silly question.

I currently populate the contents of a DropDownList in the Page_Load method of the Visual Webpart, however when something on the page posts back it causes the list to be loaded again with duplicate entries.

I can stop this from happening by wrapping the whole thing with a check for postback but i'm not sure if this is the correct way to go about it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        //Code Here
    }
}
```

My question: Is this the correct way, or should I be putting the data loading code somewhere else so that it only gets done once rather than every time the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely the correct way of handling it.